# C# mysql connector that supports proxy?

Tags: c#, mysql, proxy, mysql-connector, database-connection

I am trying to connect to mysql server database in **C#** through a proxy server, we have to use a proxy server in our university. I am using an address and a port (i.e: xxx.xxx.xx.xx, 8080).
I found a few lines of code in google that the authors claim that do the job:

```
    MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection();conn.ConnectionString = 
    Host=192.168.0.10;port=3307;user=root;password=root";
    conn.ProxyOptions.Host = "10.0.0.1";
    conn.ProxyOptions.Port = 808;
    conn.ProxyOptions.User = "ProxyUser";
    conn.ProxyOptions.Password = "ProxyPassword";
    conn.Open();
```

But my problem is that there is no definition for `ProxyOptions` in my `MySqlConnection`.
I am using `Mysql.Data.dll` and `Mysql.Web.dll`.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Which version of the MySQL Connector are you using?

Comment: I am using MySql connector 6.6.5 from dev.mysql.com.

Answer (score -1):

Found this :

```
NetworkCredential credential=new NetworkCredential("User","Password");
WebProxy proxy=new WebProxy("10.0.0.1",808);
proxy.Credentials=credential;

MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection();
conn.ConnectionString = "Host=192.168.0.10;port=3307;user=root;password=root";
conn.Proxy=proxy;
```

At CodeProject :

http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/364054/How-to-connect-to-my-sql-through-a-proxy-server-us

Seems someone was having the same problem a year ago :)

EDIT:

Take into consideration that the official MySQL.NET connector does not seem to support proxies:

http://www.devart.com/dotconnect/mysql/docs/ComparingProviders.html

The sample code you got and the one I posted was using dotConnect for MySQL (it is a 3rd party data connector)

Comment: I also found both the codes but the problem is that devart.com connectors are not opensource and are not freely available.